# EditText disapears when clicked after fragment transaction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

my EditText works perfectly fine, until you open another fragment and return back to the first one. After clicking the EditText the keyboard pops up and it looks like the soft-keyboard is pushing the content of the fragment upwards and behind the background image.

This looks something like this:

[image: before]

And after you opended a fragment and closed it again:

[image: after]

My Search Text View:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textfield"
                android:digits="@string/digits"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_normal"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorFont"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```

When this method gets called the bug happens:

```
  fun addFilter() {
    val topicList = mutableListOf<Topic?>()
    topicAdapter = TopicAdapter(topicList, context, null, true)

    if (CachedData.filter.isNotEmpty()) {

        if (CachedData.filter[0] != null) {
            filterList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            topicList.add(Topic(CachedData.filter[0], selected = true, clickable = true))
        }

        if (CachedData.filter[1] != null) {
            filterList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            if (CachedData.filter[0] == null) {
                topicAdapter.setSubselect(-1)
            }
            topicList.add(Topic(CachedData.filter[1], selected = true, clickable = true))
        }
    }
    filterList.adapter = topicAdapter
    filterList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
}
```

**UPDATE**

This only happens when something is changed in the first Fragment. For example if I add data to the dataset from the RecylerView in the first fragment the bug happens

Comment: Share your code so people can get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this wont happen before opening the second fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in the `manifest.xml` file for the coresponding activity.

Answer (score 2):

Hide soft keyboard when opened second fragment. Use this code:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            view.clearFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

and call `hideKeyboard()` method at `onPause()` of first fragment like this:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (yourEdittext!= null)
            hideKeyboard(yourEdittext);
    }
```

And `windowSoftInputMode` to your activity in manifest like this:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
        </activity>
```